# IgListKit Swift

Tags: swift, iglistkit

I'm trying to copy the Nested Adapter example, but it's not working:

From the nested adapter example:

```
private var number: Int?
    func objects(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> [ListDiffable] {
    guard let number = number else { return [] }
    return (0..<number).map { $0 as ListDiffable }
}
```

Here's what I did with my own class:

```
private var storie: Stories?

func objects(for listAdapter: ListAdapter) -> [ListDiffable] {
    guard let storie = storie else { return [] }
    return (storie as ListDiffable) as! [ListDiffable]
}
```

But I can't convert storie to [ListDiffable]

Comment: Is you ``Stories`` model conform to ``ListDiffable`` protocol? You need to implement 2 methods that go with it.